# R and RMySQL cant write table to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to write my table from R to the MySQL database.

My R code is as follows:

```
dbWriteTable(vagrant,"table1",temp,overwrite=T)
```

I have also tried deleting the existing table from the database and running without the overwrite command.

I keep receiving the error message:

```
Error in write.table(escape(value[from:to, , drop = FALSE]), file = conb,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Output from dput(head(temp))

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), date = c("2012-01-01", 
"2012-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-01-01"
), daily_avg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), daily_st_dev = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), total_duration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ratio = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), score = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), total_number = c(189L, 
30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), historic_ranking = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(date = "2012-01-01", .rows = list(
    1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It tells you wrong type so you need to reorganize the data.  Check some more examples.

Comment: Please post the `dput` of *temp*. It sounds like the data frame contains non-atomic vectors like a nested list inside a column.

Comment: how can it be the wrong type, when I havnt created the table in the database yet?

Comment: @Parfait I have dates in there, but otherwise it is just ints and floats. The `dput(temp)` produces a lot of output. The last part is: `row.names = c(NA, 
-2580L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: Provide us a few rows of *temp*: `dput(head(tmp))`.

Comment: @Parfait the output is attached

Comment: As @Parfait correctly suspected, it's a higher-level structure.  Try a plain `data.frame` object, no `tbl` or grouping.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks for the diagnosis. How could I do that? Currenly my data in in a table called "temp", would I need to create a new `data.frame`?

Comment: Try [converting](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler) with: `data.frame(temp)` as *temp* appears to be a tibble. Consider sticking with [tinyverse](http://www.tinyverse.org/) going forward!

Answer (score 0):

Following the help I received from the comments it was fixed by putting the data in a data frame and then sending to the database.

```
temp2 = data.frame(temp)
dbWriteTable(vagrant,"table1",temp2,overwrite=T)
```

Many thanks all and let me know if it could be improved.